# I'm trying to create a dictionary by counting a list but I'm getting the following TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, dictionary

Both shakespeare_words and stopwords are lists of words. I am getting the error for the second line in the for loop.

```
def count_words(shakespeare_words, stopwords):
    """Counts the words that are not stopwords.
    returns a dictionary with words as keys and values."""

    without_stopwords = [word for word in shakespeare_words if not word in stopwords]

    word_counts = dict()

    for word in without_stopwords:
        word_counts[word] = word_counts.get(word, 0) + 1

    print(word_counts)

    return word_counts
```

Comment: `shakespeare_words` seems to have at least one list inside of it. How are you calling `count_words`?

Comment: Ah I just checked shakespeare_words, it has sub lists in it that I need to fix.